# Take screenshot using selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I know how to take screenshot for specific element from the webpage. I tried several lines of code to catch the image but no one of them succeeds to capture the image well.
Here's the link of the site https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp
Here's my code and tries as for this part

```
   .Window.Maximize 
   .Get sURL
    
    
    .Wait 2000
    '.FindElementById("txtCaseNo").SendKeys "192883660"
    'DecryptCaptcha
    Dim obj As Object
    '.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='viewPane']/div").ScrollIntoView True
    .FindElementById("viewPane").ScrollIntoView True
    .Wait 2000
    '.FindElementByXPath("//div/img[@src='/captcha/imgCaptcha.jsp']").ScrollIntoView True
    '.FindElementByXPath("//div/img[@src='/captcha/imgCaptcha.jsp']").ScrollIntoView True
    
    
                'Set obj = .FindElementByXPath("//div/img[@src='/captcha/imgCaptcha.jsp']").TakeScreenshot(3000)
Set obj = .TakeScreenshot(3000)
        obj.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path + "\Number.png")
    .Wait 2000
```

I could only capture the whole page but I want to capture the element of captcha only.

Comment: Try using .ScrollIntoView().TakeScreenshot()  after you find the element.

Comment: I tried that but the same problem.

Comment: I don't think it works in VBA as it does with many other languages. But that is from memory.

Comment: A long time ago, I tried such a screenshot and it worked before in VBA.!!

Comment: @QHarr Can you help me with a code even using python?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/screenshot-element-method-selenium-python/#:~:text=screenshot()%20element%20method%20%E2%80%93%20Selenium%20Python&text=screenshot%20method%20is%20used%20to,any%20IOError%2C%20else%20return%20True.   But ensure element is visible and you don't have a cookie bar for example.

Comment: What a cookie bar? I will see the link and back if I had any problems. Hope it will work as the page doesn't let me to take a capture of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working code that solved my problem

```
Private bot As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
    Dim element As Object
    Set bot = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    With bot
        .Start
        .Get "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/searchPages/searchCases.jsp"
        Set element = .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='frmCaseNo']/div[2]/img")
        .ExecuteScript "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element
        element.TakeScreenshot(3000).SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path + "\Number.png")
    End With
End Sub
```